# mRNA extraction from mice ears.

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, proteins, rna, mrna

I am trying to extract RNA from mice ears and for some reason I don't have RNA when I perform the electrophoresis. I directly cut the ears and I put it in a tube with a bead and trizol. then I place it on ice and I use a mash machine for tissue lysis for 8 minutes and 4 ºC. After that, I perform RNA isolation according with a protocol using chloroform, isopropanol and ethanol.

I think the problem could be the extraction. Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you see a pellet when you precipitate the RNA?

Comment: yes I saw a quite big pellet, but when I do the electrophoresis using a positive control, I suposse to see either two bands or a smears if it is degraded and it doesn't appear anything like that.

Comment: Let us know the composition, buffers, running conditions (voltage etc.) of your gel.

Comment: that's not the problem, since I use the samples to do a qPCR, I have used taqman, SYBRgreen, two different machines and I dont get amplification, but I do get in a previous sample used as positive control.  So the problem is I don't have RNA in my samples. (the gel it was just to check if I have RNA and it also works with a positive control but not with my samples)

Comment: @Bio What were the A₂₆₀/A₂₈₀ and A₂₆₀/A₂₃₀ ratios? The problem could be the beads as well. Were the beads sterilized properly and kept in RNAse free conditions (in DEPC water)?

Comment: The RNA may have denatured during extraction if there is no absorbance reading after PCR. Did you produce the control sample or is it supplied?